# Temporarily disable a controller in Asp .NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way in Asp .NET MVC 2 to temporarily disable a controller in ASP .NET Mvc 2? Is there some attribute or web config element that can help me with this?

For reasons that are out of my controll I just cannot comment unwanted controller out.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could filter it through a route and direct it to a "Sorry" page.

This might help you.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/asp-net-mvc2-preview-2-areas-and-routes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Simplest one is to use [Custom ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx) on your controller that would do some custom action instead of controller actions

Comment: What if along with Custom ActionFilter a controller is decorated with [Authorize] attribute? Isn't it that for a client accessing the controller in question first login page is displayed and only after successful login my Custom ActionFilter is hit? Thats not quite what I'm looking for...

Comment: That is what you are looking for. FilterAttribute (Base of ActionFilter) has got an Order property by which you can set order of your filter attributes